# Copying using ODX between two MS Windows Server shares from desktop client

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, storage, storage-spaces, windows-server-2016

All hosts are in the domain and the setup is following:

- two MS Windows Servers 2012R2 or 2016 (named: S1, S2)
- one desktop client with newest MS Windows 10

S1 and S2 have network shares accessible from each other and desktop client.

S1, S2 and desktop client have full network connectivity between each other.

S1 and S2 have hard disks attached directly **without** any third party storage provider.

Desktop client wants to copy a very large file (2-3TB) from network share on S1 to network share on S2.

Is it possible to use some technology like ODX for the file to be **directly copied** from S1 to S2 with a command issued as a copy from desktop client.

I am aware that since MS Windows Server 2012R2 an ODX is supported with a third party storage provider which supports this technology. However I'm looking for a solution which would provide same effect but with just normal MS Windows storage.

Comment: Can box servers see each other? if so then why not just RDP into one and run the copy there, use powershell to do the same thing.

Comment: @Chopper3 all hosts have full network connectivity with each other, I'm aware of the ability to perform copy which originates on S1 or S2, or remote command execution using winrm, powershell invoke-command, etc. However I want to check if there is possibility to perform such action like ODX between two MS Windows Servers like explained above.

Answer (score 0):

ODX is a "pass-through" technology to the SAN storage layer.

Basically its instructions (tokens) that are sent to the SAN storage devices themselves.

As you do not provide any information on your storage layer, but simply refers to them as "disks", I would give a definite NO to your questions at large.

You need Storage devices that directly support ODX in order for this work.
And when you have them, you will then find out what subsets that actually provide (CVSFS, NTFS) etc.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize what you are asking: You want the copy to happen directly between the servers, at the direction of the client, initiated via a standard copy request.

The short answer is no, Windows does not have this sort of feature.